# How to sum alias column table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query sql

```
select date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
(select count(*)  from tb_media where date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = date ) as total
from tb_media group by date
```

result:

[image]

how to sum colomn total??

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
select sum(a.total) from (
select date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
(select count(*)  from tb_media where date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = date ) as total
from tb_media group by date) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 2 possible queries. The simple one (if you want the total you don't need the rest of the query) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_media
```

The less simple one :

```
SELECT SUM(t.total)
FROM (select date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
(select count(*)  from tb_media where date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = date ) as total
from tb_media group by date) AS t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your requirement then you need to count records based on date wise and also want their sum at the end and your created_on column is date type. If it is correct then you can use below query-

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),'Total') AS rep_date, 
COUNT(*) total  FROM tb_media 
GROUP BY created_at WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: If it works for you then you can mark it your choice with green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what or how you want your output data, but my best guess is you want a tabulated list with the date and the counts of each day AND a sum at the end of the table?
If it is so, this will work:

```
(select date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,count(*) 
from tb_media group by date) 
union
(select 'Total',count(*) from tb_media)
```

or if you want only the sum of all the records, the query would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_media
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
    COUNT(<put_table_key_here>) AS `total`
FROM
    tb_media
GROUP BY
    `date`;
```

**Note**

- Use the primary key or any key in the table to count the said records
- Atleast, avoid using subquery when you expect performance in your script